# jQuery- how to reverse animation on slideToggle?

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

How can I reverse animation of this toggle?

http://codepen.io/i76/pen/ozxdgY

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".clickme").click(function() {

 $(".content").slideToggle(

   function() {

     $(".hi").fadeIn();
   });
}); });
```

(And, can you spot why div with class="hi" is not centered?)

Comment: What do you mean by reverse animation? On alternate button clicks its already having the open and close animation. What behaviour you need? And centered vertically or horizontally?

Comment: At first the panel scrolls down and then the words fade in. On toggle the words go up with the panel. I'd like the words to fade out first and then for the panel to go up.
I was trying to centre 'Hello' both vertically and horizontally.